# Units of specific CRS projection?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, extract, units

I use a shapefile with CRS 
("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0").
I want to calculate a buffer around the points with 'extract' from raster package. How can I know the units in this layer? Is it in meters? My idea is to calculate 1X1 km , thus buffer=1000. Is that correct?

```
try1 <- extract(raster, 
                points,
                fun=mean, na.rm=T,
                sp = TRUE, # create spatial object
                buffer = 1000,
                method='simple',
                weights=T, 
                normalizeWeights=F)
```

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca's answer is the better way, but for a very very very rough approximation, buffer by 0.01.  (your units are decimal degrees, 1 deg ~ 111km at the equator)

Answer (score 6):

`+proj=longlat` is in angular units, degrees by default.

Better if you can project your dataset before, to a conformal projection (to preserve the circular buffer shape) appropriate for your work area (so that the distance deforms as little as possible).

Comment: Thank you!
@GabrielDeLuca Can you advise how to re-project my raster and the points?
witch CRS would be suitable to United States?

Comment: @Alina, I know how to reproject in QGIS, but are you working in R? Also, from the console, with `ogr2ogr` for the points and `gdalwarp` for the raster. United States is a large area, and it's not easy to preserve shapes and distances in larges areas. Is your work area the whole country or can it be a smaller area? I'm used to projecting in transverse mercator, tangential to an internal point of the work area, but I usually work with smaller surfaces.